# Integer Division Algorithm: question on Wiki version

Tags: algorithm, binary, division, integer-division

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Slow_division_methods) says this following algorithm is a version of long division.  Does anyone know mathematically what is happening R is being left shifted, then the least significant bit of R(0) is set to the N(i)?

I know the left shift is 2R, but I'm a little lost after that.

```
if D = 0 then error(DivisionByZeroException) end
Q := 0                  -- Initialize quotient and remainder to zero
R := 0                     
for i := n − 1 .. 0 do  -- Where n is number of bits in N
  R := R << 1           -- Left-shift R by 1 bit
  R(0) := N(i)          -- Set the least-significant bit of R equal to bit i of the numerator
  if R ≥ D then
    R := R − D
    Q(i) := 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially it is the same algorithm as we learnt in school for "division by corner" (various notation in different countries, I show ["Eurasia" one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Eurasia))

```
_176 |3_
 15   58
---   
 _26
  24
 ---   
   2
```

We put the most significant digit of dividend (1) into (temporary) remainder and check if it is larger than divisor. 1<3, so we virtually put 0 into quotient and make remainder 17 - this is `1*10 + 7`, in binary `R := R << 1; R(0) := N(i)`

17>3, so we subtract product of divisor and max possible digit of quotient. Here 3*5, we put 5 into quotient, in binary version digit of quotient in case of `R ≥ D` is 1 (`Q(i) := 1`)

At the second step we multiply remainder 2 by 10 and add the next digit 6. In binary version equivalent is `R := R << 1; R(0) := N(i)` and so on.